# Angular Material Bottom Sheet Won't Close On Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am having trouble with Angular Materia's Bottom Sheet. I can get it to fire open but I can't get the menu to close when a button is clicked. It will close when clicked elsewhere, but not if one of the buttons in the bottom sheet is selected. There is a working Code Pen demo for demonstration. All help is appreciated.

**Code Pen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGBGgJ

**HTML**

```
<body layout="row" ng-controller="BottomSheetController">
  <div layout="column" layout-fill flex class="set-page-background" ng-controller="BottomSheetController">

<md-toolbar class="md-tall contact-tall">
  <div layout="column" class="md-toolbar-tools-bottom inset" layout-fill layout-align="center start">

    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">

      <!-- BOTTOM SHEET BUTTON -->
      <div flex="10" ng-click="openBottomSheet()">
        <md-button>Open Sheet</md-button>
     </div>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons']);

app.controller('BottomSheetController', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
$scope.openBottomSheet = function() {
  $mdBottomSheet.show({
    template: '<md-bottom-sheet class="btm-list">' +
    '<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn">Add</md-button>'  +
    '<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn">Delete</md-button>'  +
    '<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn">Append</md-button>'  +
    '<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn">Show</md-button>'  +
    '<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn cancel-btn">Cancel</md-button>'  +

    '</md-bottom-sheet>'
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('You clicked the button to close the bottom sheet!');
  })

  // Fires when the cancel() method is used
  .catch(function() {
    console.log('You hit escape or clicked the backdrop to close.');
  });
}
$scope.closeBottomSheet = function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $mdBottomSheet.hide();
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `closeBottomSheet()` parameters in js file. this is sample code you can refer

```
 $scope.closeBottomSheet = function() {

        $mdBottomSheet.hide();
      }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.openBottomSheet = function() {
  
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
     controller:'MyController',
      template: '<md-bottom-sheet>' +
      'Hello! <md-button ng-click="closeBottomSheet()">Close</md-button>' +
      '</md-bottom-sheet>'
    })

    // Fires when the hide() method is used
    .then(function() {
      console.log('You clicked the button to close the bottom sheet!');
    })

    // Fires when the cancel() method is used
    .catch(function() {
      console.log('You hit escape or clicked the backdrop to close.');
    });
  };

  $scope.closeBottomSheet = function() {
   
    $mdBottomSheet.hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <md-button ng-click="openBottomSheet()">
    Open a Bottom Sheet!
  </md-button>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template for the cancel button you need to call the function wich close the bottomsheet.

```
'<md-button class="btm-sheet-btn cancel-btn" ng-click="closeBottomSheet()" >Cancel</md-button>'
```

Here is the sample on the material documentation

[Example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdBottomSheet)

Also here is a plunker -> [Example 2](https://embed.plnkr.co/F2PxL9/)

Comment: While your answer works in theory, it doesn't work in my example. When I add ng-click="closeBottomSheet()" it does not close the Bottom Sheet. I added it to cancel and it did nothing in my CodePen demo.